# Customer address attributes of type datetime and decimal cannot be cleared from the admin

Tags: magento-1.9, eav, customer-address

I have added custom `datetime` and `decimal` attributes to the *customer address* entity using update scripts such that they can be edited via the admin. Although it is possible to *add* or *update* the attribute values, it is not possible to *clear* them.

When adding similar attributes to the *customer* entity, it is possible to clear those attributes.

I am wondering what could the cause of this issue. Looks like a Magento bug to me.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the backend models of customer address attributes are not fully loaded by the method `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::getAddressesCollection`: the `value_id` from the corresponding backend tables are not loaded into the backend models, which makes it impossible to delete attribute values when saving an entity.

The root cause of the problem is that the method `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract::setEntityValueId` is not called on the backend models. This leads to the following issue when calling `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::save($object)`:

- First `_collectSaveData` is called on `$object`, which divides the attribute values that are changed into three arrays: `$insert`, `$update` and `$delete`. Each  `$update` and `$delete` entry is an array containing a `value_id` element; its value is determined by calling `$attribute->getBackend()->getEntityValueId($newObject)`... but this is always empty since the corresponding setter was not called.
- Second `_processSaveData` is called on the previously determined arrays. The `$insert` and `$update` arrays are used to fill the `_attributeValuesToSave` instance variable, and while doing this the `$value_id` element from the elements of the `$update` array is discarded. The `$delete` array is used to fill the `_attributeValuesToDelete` instance variable... but this does not contain anything useful, because only empty values are added. At the end of the method, `_processAttributeValues` is called to perform the actual database changes; for the `_attributeValuesToDelete` array, the statement `$adapter->delete($table, array('value_id IN (?)' => $valueIds)` is executed, which is useless, since `$valueIds` only contains empty values.

One way of solving this issue, is to use `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::load` method on each customer address that needs to be save. This method calls `_loadModelAttributes`, which in turn calls the `_setAttributeValue` method for each attribute, which makes sure the current `value_id` is set on the corresponding backend model by calling `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract::setEntityValueId`.

The easiest way to achieve this is by replacing the method `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::getAddressesCollection` with the following implementation:

```
public function getAddressesCollection()
{
    if ($this->_addressesCollection === null) {
        $this->_addressesCollection = $this->getAddressCollection()
            ->setCustomerFilter($this);
        /** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Address $address */
        foreach ($this->_addressesCollection as $address) {
            /** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Address $addressResource */
            $addressResource = $address->getResource();
            $addressResource->load($address, $address->getId());
            $address->setCustomer($this);
        }
    }
    return $this->_addressesCollection;
```

Some other points of interest:

- Clearing customer address attribute values of type `varchar` and `text` from the admin does not cause any issues, but only because the corresponding records in the database are *updated* with the empty string instead of *deleted*. The reason for this is that Magento uses the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract::isValueEmpty` method to determine whether an existing attribute value should be deleted (`true`) or updated (`false`). This method only considers an empty string to be empty when the backend type is `int`, `decimal` or `datetime` (and not when it is `varchar` or `text`).
- The use of `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::load` also calls the `_afterLoad` method, which calls `afterLoad` on all backend models. On default Magento installations, this is implemented only for the `created_at` attribute: the value is converted from UTC to the current store time zone. Since the (converted) value is converted back to UTC on save, absence of the `afterLoad` call leads to incorrect `created_at` dates.