# When saving a customer via the admin, the created_at value of all its addresses change

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-address

When saving a customer from the admin, the `created_at` value of all the addresses belonging to the customer are changed by a number of hours.

The number of hours that the `created_at` value changes depends on the configured timezone for the store:

- When using `Pacific Standard Time (America/Los_Angeles)`, which is UTC/GMT-7, the `created_at` value is *increased* by 7 hours on each save.
- When using `W.Europe Standard Time (Europe/Berlin)`, which is UTC/GMT+2, on each customer save, the `created_at` value is *decreased* by 2 hours on each save.
- When using `UTC (Etc/GMT)`, the `created_at` value stays the same on each save.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the `afterLoad` methods are not called on the backend models of the customer address attributes: in the method `Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController::saveAction`, the customer addresses are loaded via a collection by using the method `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::getAddressesCollection`. Collection loads do not trigger the `afterLoad` events of the attribute backend models.

In a default Magento installation, the backend models of the `customer_address` attributes do not implement the `afterLoad` methods, except for one: the class `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created` corresponding to the `created_at` attribute.

This class tries to make sure that the `created_at` value is stored in the database in UTC format and is made available to the user in the current store time zone, by providing the following methods:

- `afterLoad`: the `created_at` data value is converted from UTC to the current store time zone.
- `beforeSave`: the `created_at` date value is converted from the current store time zone to UTC.

Because the `afterLoad` method is never called, but the `beforeSave` method is, the leads to incorrect values.

To resolve this, the `afterLoad` method needs to be triggered.

One way of doing this is by changing the implementation of `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::getAddressesCollection` such that each customer address is loaded using a full load:

```
public function getAddressesCollection()
{
    if ($this->_addressesCollection === null) {
        $this->_addressesCollection = $this->getAddressCollection()
            ->setCustomerFilter($this);
        /** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Address $address */
        foreach ($this->_addressesCollection as $address) {
            /** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Address $addressResource */
            $addressResource = $address->getResource();
            $addressResource->load($address, $address->getId());
            $address->setCustomer($this);
        }
    }
    return $this->_addressesCollection;
}
```

This is the same replacement implementation I suggested in [Customer address attributes of type datetime and decimal cannot be cleared from the admin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/117493/13773), which also resolves the issue that customer address attributes of type datetime and decimal cannot be cleared from the admin.